# Change colors of Nav elements On Hover in CSS

Tags: css

How do I get the "brand-logo" and all the li's on the right side of the nav to change to black when I hover over the nav itself. The nav already changes to #FFF on a hover:

https://codepen.io/thomaschsu/pen/qJvVWm

HTML:

```
<nav id="nav">
  <div class="nav-wrapper">
    <span id="logo-container" class="brand-logo">Example</span>
    <div>
      <ul class="right">
        <li class="active"><a href="/">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="/contact">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="/portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
        <li><a href="/resume">Resume</a></li>
        <li><a class="waves-effect email-btn" href="mailto:example@gmail.com">email me</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

CSS:

```
body {
  background-color: #222;
}

nav:hover {
  background: #fff;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  color: #222;
}

nav .nav-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}

nav {
  background: transparent;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  color: #fff;
  width: 100%;
  height: 90px;
  line-height: 56px;
  display: block;
}

nav .brand-logo {
  position: absolute;
  color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 2.1rem;
  padding: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

nav ul li.active {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

nav ul a:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

nav ul li {
  transition: background-color 0.3s;
  float: left;
  padding: 0;
}
nav ul a {
  transition: background-color 0.3s;
  font-size: 1rem;
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
  padding: 0 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.right {
  float: right;
}
ul:not(.browser-default) {
  padding-left: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}
.email-btn {
  background: transparent;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 20px;
}
.waves-effect {
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
  vertical-align: middle;
  z-index: 1;
  transition: 0.3s ease-out;
}
```

I've already tried adding "color: #222" to nav:hover, which has no affect on any of the text in the nav.

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use this:

```
nav:hover #logo-container, nav:hover ul li a {
  color: #000;  
}
```

It means: When a user hovers over the nav the "internal" #logo-container and links must have their text color changed to black.

Comment: Thank you for the fast response!

What I intended to do was make the text black, not the background, so this was more so what I was looking for, except, I still can't get the list items on the right to turn black:

nav:hover #logo-container, nav ul li {
  color: #000;  
}
Any suggestions?